# Proving a triangle is isoceles given two points on the sides

Tags: geometry

Here is the problem

A $\triangle NML$ is given. On the sides $NM$ and $ML$ respectively points $A$ and $B$ are chose so that $ {NA \over AM} = {MB\over BL} = 2 $ and $ \angle NLM = 2\angle MBA$. Prove that $\triangle NML$ is isosceles.

I'm pretty much stuck with it as I don't really know how to approach this problem. I feel that it probably requires extending certain lines or something similar. One thing that I have thought about is that if you draw a line through $B$, parallel to $NL$ you'll end up with a triangle, similar to $\triangle NML$ in which $BA$ is an angle bisector.

Any help with this will be very appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close, everything you need has been mentioned, and you just need to put your thoughts together.

Let $C$ on $NM$ be the point such that $CB \parallel NL$.

**Hint:** What can you say about point $C$ on line $NM$? Can you find $\frac{NC}{CM}$?

**Hint:** What is $\frac{CA}{AM}$?

**Hint:** You mentioned that $BA$ is the angle bisector. So, apply the angle bisector theorem to $\triangle CBM$. What does this tell you that $\triangle CBM$ is isosceles

**Hint:** You mentioned that $\triangle CBM$ is similar to $\triangle CLM$. Hence, it is isosceles.

Comment: Thank you, I sometimes am not that good at putting all the parts I have together.